# Is it possible to use Swift Package compiled for macOS Catalyst in a native macOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift-package-manager, mac-catalyst

I have a native macOS app written with AppKit.
Now I want to integrate some external Swift Package but it's only available on iOS and macOS Catalyst.
Is there any way to include such package in the native macOS app or does it have to compile natively as well?

Comment: Does the external Swift package use any UI classes from iOS or Catalyst? If so, then I think it's definitely a "no".

Comment: What's the lib (if public)? Is it compiler source (framework) or source code (that will compile)?

Comment: @Larme Unsplash (https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-photopicker-ios) - it’s a source code, distributed with Swift Package. I’m happy to fork it and change a source a little if needed as long as I don’t have to rewrite UI from scratch.